# Make a static reference to non static field android

Tags: java, android, xml, static, getresource

I trying to develop an android app, where I need to make a static(PLACES_API_BASE) reference to a non-static variable.Please check out the below code.

```
private static final String PLACES_API_BASE= getResources().getString(R.string.places_api_base);
```

But, I am getting an error stating,

```
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getResources() from the type
```

Is there any possible work around to achieve this. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Does it have to be `final`?

Comment: @adavis `final` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @alfasin well, yes it does for me.  If it doesn't have to be final then he can create a setter for it, or initialize it in a create() method.

Comment: @adavis "for me" has no place here - it is not a personal issue. See the link that Brian posted above for more details.

Comment: The point being that `final` isn't the real issue here; not understanding objects is.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot make a static reference to the non-static method because the method is "attached" to an instance (object scope) which the "static" reference (class scope) is not "aware" of.

Answer (score 0):

No way.
**getResources** is an instance method. So any way you should create an instance before calling it. And **PLACES_API_BASE** is and class constant, which does not belong to any instance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can fix it:

```
private final String mPlacesApiBase;

// constructor
public YourClass(Context context) {
    mPlacesApiBase = context.getResources().getString(R.string.places_api_base);
```

If your class is an activity/service, put the initialization in `onCreate()` instead:

```
private String mPlacesApiBase;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    mPlacesApiBase = getString(R.string.places_api_base);
```

I changed the variable name. By Java conventions, `ALL_CAPS_IDENTIFIERS` are for constants known at compile time and not for things initialized dynamically. The prefix `m` is the convention for member variables. I also removed the `static` as it doesn't seem to be necessary here.

Comment: I want the mPlacesApiBase to be static. I am using it else where so. I cant remove static modifier.

Comment: You can have it but you shouldn't need it.

Comment: I need it. I am using it else where.So how is it possible?

Comment: Bad practice. Your app will be dying ever so often. You can still use the @laalto solution. Just add static to the declaraction. The key thing is that it HAS to be initialized in a non static context (ex. the constructor)

Answer (score -1):

Create an object and then call method getResources() in a method or constructor.

Comment: -1 you could also say: "make the method `getResources()` static. It doesn't answer the question but rather try to "patch" the problem without real understanding of the issue. Bad practice!

Comment: @Dave has asked for a workaround. So i have tried to give way the same.